# Save a password in the Browser on a Flex login

Tags: apache-flex, browser, passwords

Is it possible to have the browser identify a Flex login form and suggest "Save Password"?

If no, is there some elegant workaround?

Comment: I didn't think this was possible.  All the browser sees, in terms of Flex, is the big "Plugin" Box.

Comment: Possibly there there might be a plugin that takes care of this, but I think the best solution would be to implement this support into your application and simply utilize the FlashPlayers local storage (Something similar to Browser Cookies).

Comment: you can save password using sharedObjects..

Comment: With regards to the detection of the form, you could use the ExternalInterface api to detect a form using javascript and then pass your findings back into the flex application using a callback function?

Answer (score 0):

Check this example .. It is using Shared Objects.(i have used the same and working fine).

[Login With Remember Password](http://www.flexer.info/2008/05/09/using-shared-objects-login-process-with-remember-password/)

Comment: But isn't it much less secure than the browser storing the password?

Comment: it will not save password in system cache but it will stored in Browser cache. if you saved password in one browser you will not get this information in other browsers...

Comment: I meant insecure in the sense that it is stored plainly without any encryption (if I understand Shared Objects correctly).

Comment: ya its sure but you can use some encryption methods.. in given link author specified about encryption.. (comments).